# Cycles is not baking my duplicated faces

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals, baking

I am creating a seamless texture in blender using a duplication method on a plane with 9 faces. I have objects parented to that face. On that face, I have the option for dedication set to faces and it allows me to tile the objects to make a seamless texture map. I have another plane above the objects that I'm baking too, and when I go to bake, it will only bake the normals for the objects themselves and not the duplicated faces. Is there a setting or something that will allow it to bake the normals on duplicated faces?

[image]